# Search doesn't work in Android Studio's "Choose Library Dependency"

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

I'm trying to find: gson, mockito, glide, picasso etc. Only com.android.support:* can be found.
Android Studio 3.0.1 & 3.1 Canary 5
In Studio 2 worked fine.

[image: illustration]

Q: How can I fix it?
P.S. I know how to add they manually.

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.1 of Android Studio, no result for searches.

Comment: found the fix? I'm having this issue too

Answer (score 0):

I tried searching on Android Studio 3.1 Beta 2 and it's works fine. However on Android Studio 3.0.1 search doesn't work. 
I guess there is no way to fix it exept updating IDE.
You can try Android Studio 3.1 Beta 2, follow the link for downloading: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html

Note: don't update your stable version to beta. Instead install alongside your stable version: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html